# I'm trying to make a basic movement script in unity, but an error keeps showing up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a basic movement script in unity, but it keeps showing up with the error:

> Assets\Move.cs(5,14): error CS1106: Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

I then tried adding the static keyword to the extension (TransformExtension), and everything in it, but ended up with the errors:

> Assets\Move.cs(27,10): error CS0708: 'Start': cannot declare instance members in a static class

> Assets\Move.cs(33,10): error CS0708: 'Update': cannot declare instance members in a static class

> Assets\Move.cs(38,10): error CS0708: 'move': cannot declare instance members in a static class

So then I added the static keyword to the functions Start, Update and move.

Then I end up with the errors:

> Assets\Move.cs(42,32): error CS0103: The name 'transform' does not exist in the current context

> Assets\Move.cs(43,13): error CS0103: The name 'transform' does not exist in the current context

They are essentially telling me to remove the static keywords so move() can access the extension, but if I do that, I will end up in the same way as before.

I will show the code I did along the way below, though I believe it was the second set of errors that I interpreted wrong.

Original

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour

{

    public float speed;

}


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() //
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() //
    {
        move();
    }

    void move() //
    {
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            float upArrowOld = transform.position;
            transform.SetY(upArrowOld + 1);
        }
    }
}

public class TransformExtentions

{

    public void SetX(this Transform transform, float x)

    {

    transform.position = new Vector3(x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);

    }

    public void SetY(this Transform transform, float y)

    {

    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, y, transform.position.z);

    }

    public void SetZ(this Transform transform, float z)

    {

    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, z);

}
```

**After 1st step**

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour

{

    public float speed;

}


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() 
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() 
    {
        move();
    }

    void move() 
    {
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            float upArrowOld = transform.position;
            transform.SetY(upArrowOld + 1);
        }
    }
}

public static class TransformExtentions

{

    public static void SetX(this Transform transform, float x)

    {

    transform.position = new Vector3(x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);

    }

    public static void SetY(this Transform transform, float y)

    {

    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, y, transform.position.z);

    }

    public static void SetZ(this Transform transform, float z)

    {

    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, z);

}
```

***Final**

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour

{

    public float speed;

}


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    static void Start() 
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    static void Update()
    {
        move();
    }

    static void move()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            float upArrowOld = transform.position;
            transform.SetY(upArrowOld + 1);
        }
    }
}

public static class TransformExtentions

{

    public static void SetX(this Transform transform, float x)

    {

    transform.position = new Vector3(x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);

    }

    public static void SetY(this Transform transform, float y)

    {

    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, y, transform.position.z);

    }

    public static void SetZ(this Transform transform, float z)

    {

    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, z);

}
```

**Edit (Thank you to Kit, derHugo and Tomas Bruna)**

**I added an another } to the end of the script (for the extension), removed the 'this' keywords from the extension, and removed the } after public float speed; . However, I ended up with the following errors:**

**Assets\Move.cs(26,32): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Vector3' to 'float'**

**Assets\Move.cs(27,23): error CS1061: 'Transform' does not contain a definition for 'SetY' and no accessible extension method 'SetY' accepting a first argument of type 'Transform' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

**My new code is the following below:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() //
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() //
    {
        move();
    }

    void move() //
    {
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            float upArrowOld = transform.position;
            transform.SetY(upArrowOld + 1);
        }
    }
}

public class TransformExtentions
{
    public void SetX(Transform transform, float x)
    {
    transform.position = new Vector3(x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    }
    public void SetY(Transform transform, float y)
    {
    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, y, transform.position.z);
    }
    public void SetZ(Transform transform, float z)
    {
    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, z);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a typo: Remove that `}` after `private float speed;` ... and no `Start` and `Update` etc can definitely not be `static` they belong to an **instance** of a `MonoBehviour`!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe removing keyword `this` from the parameters of the methods would help.

Try:

```
public void SetX(Transform transform, float x)
```

Instead of:

```
public void SetX(this Transform transform, float x)
```